# Link MS Excel data to MS Project (but with a twist)

Tags: excel, ms-project

I know how to link Excel cells to a Project file (paste special, paste link, text data, ...), but I'm having issues with where that link points *not* changing when I add lines or sort a column in Excel.

**Example:**

Cell B1 in Excel contains a date for when Product A (in A1) is ready to ship. I want to put this date into Project so the successors are updated based on changes to this date.

Adding a line in Excel to add Product B above line 1 *pushes Product A down to line 2*, making the date appear in B2. *Project does not recognize this change* and continues to link to B1, which is actually the date for Product B now.

**How can I get Project to link to dates related to specific products rather than specific cells?**

Can Project search through the products column (A) for the right product and then link the date from its corresponding column (B)?

Answer (score 0):

Use a "dummy sheet" for the MS project link.

Eg :

In Sheet1, cell A1&B1 is the original product & date. In sheet2, cell A1, put `=Sheet1!A1` in & in sheet2, cell B1, put `=Sheet1!B1`.

Then link the MS project to sheet2 A1 & B1 instead of the original data in sheet1.

Then if you insert a row/change column in Sheet1, the will not affect the cell location in Sheet2.

Please share if it works/not.

Comment: What you suggest works in Excel, but it's the lines I'm interested in copying, not the columns. You say to put data into A1 and B1, but I need to look at data in A1 and A2. If I do it by rows (yours is by columns), then the trick with sheet2 doesn't work. If I sort sheet1, it changes the data in sheet2 because it continues to link to the cell and not the data, if that makes sense... at least that's what I'm seeing.

Comment: Sorting was not mentioned in the original question .. that's why this solution is proposed. ( :  "If I do it by rows (yours is by columns), then the trick with sheet2 doesn't work." > Nope, It'll still work. have a try. | " If I sort sheet1,..." :  IMHO, If you sort by drag and drop.. the above solution will still work. | Just to prevent more assuption.. would you mind sharing some screenshot of how the data looks like before & after the sorting?